# NUnit test for Void function (Sending Email)

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a void function, which sends email. I need to write tests for this ​​function. How can this be done?

```
public void SendAdminMail(string subject, string body, string adminAddress)
    {

        var email = Email.
            From(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mail.NoReply.Address"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).
            To(adminAddress).
            Subject(subject).
            Body(body).
            UsingClient(GetOfficeClient());
        email.Message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        email.Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        email.Send();
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx

Comment: What you want to do is called mocking... And is 99% of the times connected to dependency injection... Without one or the other it's very complex to do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context it would be very hard - unless you'll be able to switch `Email` somehow through reflection (as interestingly pointed out by [juhan_h in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269368/2642204), maybe not that hard nowadays ;) ).

Typical solution is to provide an interface for your class, for example `interface EmailFactory`. Then you'd have:

```
private EmailFactory emailFactory;
public void SendAdminMail(string subject, string body, string adminAddress)
{
    var email = emailFactory
        .From(ConfigurationManager
                  .AppSettings["Mail.NoReply.Address"]
                  .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        .To(adminAddress)
        .Subject(subject)
        .Body(body)
        .UsingClient(GetOfficeClient());

    email.Message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    email.Message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    email.Send();
}
```

And then you could provide a stub of this factory to your class, which would create email mocks on which you could verify the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate or Premium then you can generate Fakes assembly for the `System.Net.Mail` assembly and use that.

More info on Fakes can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx).

If you do not have VS2012 Ultimate or Premium then my answer is complete usless :)

Comment: Fakes is also included in VS2012 Premium since this update: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2013/01/30/announcing-visual-studio-2012-update-2-vs2012-2.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I am starting to think that unit tests should work when the network cable is unplugged.


What do you actually want to test?


You could use a mock or fake and verify that you have called methods as expected. 

It might prove to be more useful to be able to stub out this class and use the stub elsewhere to make sure the rest of your tests don't send emails every time they are run.

Answer (score 1):

> How can this be done ?

It is not straightforward to test this method unless you use certain libraries or frameworks to do a lot of workarounds because your method violates the SRP principle.

Although your method is called SendAmdinMail, there is only a single statement that actually handles sending, being `email.Send()` and the rest of method is building the mail message using the .NET API.

You should break this method into different parts like CreateMailBody, CreateHeader, LoadMailConfig and hide mail sending behind an abstraction *(interface, abstract class)* so you can create a mock of the mail sending service.

This way you can also test the contents of the message body, you can test recipients, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What you are wanting to write is an [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) rather than a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing).

If you want to test that your code calls some function that would be responsible for sending an email then you want to write a unit test through the use of some sort of mocking frameworks such as [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/).

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSendEmail()
{
    IEmailService mockEmailService = Substitute.For<IEmailService>();
    MyEmailSendingThingy thingUnderTest = new MyEmailSendingThingy(mockEmailService);

    thingUnderTest.DoSomeWorkThatInvolvesSendingEmails();

    mockEmailService.Received().SendEmail("foo@foo.foo", "bar@bar.bar", "Subject", "Some Text");
}
```

If you want to test that your application actually sends an email you want to write an integration test. There are a number of ways you can achieve this.

1. Write a test that waits for a period of time and then retrieves emails from the test email account and verifies that it got the message it was expecting.
2. Send the emails to an internal SMTP server which is set up to store the emails in a drop folder which can then be checked by the test code.
3. Mock out an SMTP endpoint and mimic the responses that something calling an SMTP server would expect. You can then verify with your endpoint that it received the email it was expecting.
4. Mock out the System.Mail components using [Moles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798506.aspx) or Fakes.

1 and 2 require a lot of effort and you have to take into account the asynchronous nature of sending the emails. This will mean you will have to sleep your program or use some sort of trigger to wait for the emails to arrive at their destination which should be avoided where possible.

3 Is my personal choice for three reasons. You can host it within the test process making it easier to do your assertions. Secondly it is reusable and can be used in any test framework. And thirdly as a bonus you get a better understanding of how email works.

4 Personally I do not like mocking static or concrete components.. It can lead to bad habits and bad code. However a tool used the right way can be a useful thing and this might be the best way for you to test this part of your code.

**Finally make sure you are testing the right thing.** You should not need to test that Microsoft has written the System.Email components correctly, you just need to make sure that you are calling the components correctly.